# To write and execute sub-queries in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
Event_id    place   money
101         1       120
101         2       60
101         3       30
102         1       10
102         2       5
102         3       2
103         1       100
103         2       60
103         3       40
401         1       1000
401         2       500
401         3       250
401         4       100
401         5       50
```

I'm trying to write and execute SQL sub-queries.So far I have come up with this but I just can't seem to finish it off to get the outcome I want.

```
select event_id,
(select money from prize where ) as First, 
(select money from prize where ) as Second, 
(select money from prize where ) as Third
from prize AS prize2
group by event_id;
```

This is my expected outcome:

```
Event_id    First   Second  Third
101         120     60      30
```

Comment: Primary key should be unique

Comment: Unless you have been told to do so you shouldn't use sub queries for this, You should search for mysql conditional aggregation.And please add sample data and expected output as text rather than images.

Comment: I've been told to do it this way.

Comment: *"I've been told to do it this way."* is this  homework or job interview related question? -> [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: can you show db table records?

Comment: @blazer338 What primary key? Not all tables have (or need) a primary key. For this example it's not relevant. And who's to say the primary isn't a compound key of (`event_id,place`) for example?

Comment: you don't have any idea about the primary key? so why you are using Group by?

Comment: @RajendraSingh What does a primary key have to do with it? A `group by` should be used on **all non-aggregated** fields, be they primary key or not.

Comment: A column or group of columns in a table which helps us to uniquely identifies every row in that table is called a primary key. This DBMS can't be a duplicate. The same value can't appear more than once in the table.

Comment: @Chambo the answer which is the solution of your answer marked as accept answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming place equates to first,second,third etc then correlated sub queries might be what you are looking for

```
select event_id,
(select money from t t1 where place = 1 and t1.event_id = t.event_id ) as First, 
(select money from t t1 where place = 2 and t1.event_id = t.event_id ) as Second, 
(select money from t t1 where place = 3 and t1.event_id = t.event_id ) as Third
from t
group by event_id;

+----------+-------+--------+-------+
| event_id | First | Second | Third |
+----------+-------+--------+-------+
|      101 |   120 |     60 |    30 |
|      102 |    10 |      5 |     2 |
|      103 |   100 |     60 |    40 |
|      401 |  1000 |    500 |   250 |
+----------+-------+--------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But this is an invalid use of group by since there is no aggregation going on. And you would need to apply a where clause to limit to even_id 101.

Comment: *"But this is an invalid use of group by since there is no aggregation going on"* No it's valid co-related subqueries outputs are not group by depend..  See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jQzs7p23TiEMXb5NCSBXNw/0) -> sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is active..

Comment: @Raymond Nijland  Poor wording on my part, I would never do this query this way.

Comment: *"Poor wording on my part"* Yes i see what you meant instead of invalid you meant unlogic as it indeed does not make sense to use group by without aggregation, using DISTINCT would make more sense..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want the first, second, and third to have the following result:

```
Event_id|First|Second|Third|
--------|-----|------|-----|
     101|  120|    60|   30|
     102|   10|     5|    2|
     103|  100|    60|   40|
     401| 1000|   500|  250|
```

You can skip subqueries and use `if` and `sum`.
Here is what you can aim for:

```
SELECT Event_id
, SUM(if (place = 1, money, null)) AS `First`
, SUM(if (place = 2, money, null)) AS `Second`
, SUM(if (place = 3, money, null)) AS `Third`
FROM prize
GROUP by Event_id
```

Now a little explanation. For each row, you extract if the `money` should be in the first, second, or third column. When you have those value extracted, you can group by `Event_id` and sum all values.

If you need more values, you just need to add extra columns.

Comment: Much better query to get the result if only need first,second and third places.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed 3 columns then use this

```
select prize2.event_id,
 (select money from prize where event_id= prize2.event_id order by place limit 0,1) as First, 
 (select money from prize where event_id= prize2.event_id order by place limit 1,1) as Second, 
 (select money from prize where event_id= prize2.event_id order by place limit 2,1) as Third
from prize AS prize2
group by event_id;
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fgBRFi84KzuoANHVU1keAw/2)

Comment: this query has **no meaning** at all as SQL tables/resultsets are by standards **orderless**.. Meaning more or less you should not use `limit` without `order by` but then still the results can be non deterministic (random) in cases off ties..

Comment: OP did not ask first-second third are order ..but we can do this if require

Comment: Thank you Mangesh, that was a big help.

Comment: i think you didn't catch mine point.. using `limit 0,1`  to fetch the "first" record is the wrong approach as the "first" record can be anny record which matches the WHERE clause as MySQL is free to return a matching record in anny order without `ORDER BY` clause..

Comment: @Raymond Nijland I suspect first,second, third are place in the table.

Comment: @Raymond where clause filter according to outer grouped event_id, so for each group id there are only 3 records ..check my demo ?? and apologize for not understanding your point.

Comment: *" I suspect first,second, third are place in the table."* i know @P.Salmon iam talking about this query is not how it should be done..

Comment: @RaymondNijland As place are already sorted, still we can add order by on place .check updated demo

Comment: *"As place are already sorted, still we can add order by on place"* you need to add the `ORDER BY` it is not a matter of can  -> *"SQL tables/resultsets are by standards orderless."* But now the query is correct so i upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, May be it can help

```
SELECT Event_id,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(money), ',',1), ',', -1) AS First, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(money), ',',2), ',', -1) AS Second,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(money), ',',3), ',', -1) AS Third
FROM `prize` WHERE place in (1,2,3) GROUP BY Event_id order By Event_id ASC
```